# Visual Studio 2012 Resources1.Designer.vb created instead of updating Resources.Designer.vb

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

So the title basically explains it all.  Whenever I try to import a resource, Visual Studio is creating a Resources1.Designer.vb file instead of adding the new resource property to Resources.Designer.vb.

I have found a temporary solution: Open Resources1.Designer.vb, search for the property, copy/paste the property into Resources.Designer.vb, and then delete Resources1.Designer.vb.

This solution is really time consuming though.  Has anyone else experienced this, or does anyone know of a real/true fix?  I've searched here, google, and MSDN.  MSDN has an article from VS 2010, but no true solutions were ever proposed.

So to clarify, this happens *anytime* through *any method* of importing a resource.  Project, Properties, Add Existing,  ... SelectedControl, Properties Pane, Image, Import Project Resource, or double-clicking on My Project, Resources.resx, then Add Existing.

Comment: I would guess that you accidentally added a .resx file to your project.  Your project also has the normal "Resources.resx" file but the IDE hides it.  Click the Show All Files icon in the Solution Explorer window toolbar so you can see everything.  Resources.resx is under the My Project node.  If you see another .resx file then you ought to consider deleting it.

Comment: You can also edit the vbproj file to correct the file names if its bothering you.

Comment: Show all files already on.  only .resx is Resources.resx.  Expanding that shows Resources.Designer.vb.  When I add a resource, it creates Resources1.Designer.vb under Resources.resx

Comment: StingyJack, turn that into an answer and I'll 1 up it.  I'm not sure how it was modified (we're on TFS so who knows), but in the vbproj:

      <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.vb</LastGenOutput>


LastGenOutput was Resources1.Designer.vb (only occurance in the file).  Changed it to Resources.Designer.vb and so far it appears to be working.

Comment: I am using Git. So what I did was I discarded the csproj change in git, deleted the old Resources.Designer.cs and renamed Resources1.Designer.cs to Resources.Designer.cs, then opened the project back. This looks to me like a bug in Visual Studio.

Comment: Also, I have this problem in VS 2013 premium update 3.

Comment: Visual Studio Community 2015 Update 3 too.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Edit the vbproj (csproj) manualy in text editor - remove the number **1**

`<LastGenOutput>Resources1.Designer.vb</LastGenOutput>`

Comment: Sorry it took so long to upvote/mark.  I wasn't very active back then, this just popped back up for an upvote on the OP and I noticed I hadn't selected one.  My bad.

Comment: You might also need to add the tag if it doesn't exist. A colleague of mine deleted the tag in a merge by accident

Comment: I had the same problem today on a Razor ASP.NET C# Project, and the solution was the same: Edit the csproj manually in text editor - remove the number **1**: 
`<LastGenOutput>Resources1.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>` . I just added the comment here for Internet search browsers, such as Google, to crawl for this text. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

1. Open MyProject\folder, you will see two files: Resource.Designer.vb (I am using vb.net) and Resource1.Designer.vb. Delete the latter.
2. Go back up one level, open the application project file: xxx.vbproj using a text editor, search for 'Resources' keyword, you will see two 'Compile' tags for Resource and Resource1. Comment out the second part, like this:

   ```
   <Compile Include="My Project\Resources.Designer.vb">
     <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
     <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
     <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
   </Compile>
   <!-- <Compile Include="My Project\Resources1.Designer.vb">
     <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
     <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
     <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
   </Compile> -->
   ```

3. Save and rebuild the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Although I do not have an answer to the problem, my workaround was just opening the two files in a comparison tool (e.g. **WinMerge**) and analyze the differences and select the ones I need accordingly. Is is easy to move code from one file to the other and then you can safely delete/remove from project the newly created `Resource1` file.

Answer (score 0):

The other two answers by Joe Wu and Michal Minich are partially right, but I've found you need to do a bit more to fix this.

Chances are good if you edit your proj file to change `Resources1` to just `Resources` you'll end up with two references in your proj file to the exact same resources file, `Resources`, which will still cause you some problems.

So simply delete all the references to Resources1 in the project file, and delete the Resources1 file. That fixed the issue for me, and doesn't cause the `Resources1` file to keep on reappearing whenever I add something to the resources.